# aptana development environment setup with laptop/desktop

Tags: git, aptana, development-environment

How would you **correctly** setup a desktop (win7) and mac osx laptop to work in Aptana using GIT?  *I think that I am doing this wrong.*

I believe my problem is that ".project" files are being overwritten at each push/pull when switching between machines. This causes a constant loop of deleting the project, adding the project, conf git, pull, dev, push.

Example:  I dev on desktop, push to repo (my server), pull down to laptop, aptana kicks an error stating that the project file is corrupt and cannot be opened.  This works vice versa if i dev on laptop and pull to desktop.

I tried gitignore and that doesn't work.

This has been going on for 3 days know and i'm circling in git/aptana/project madness.  Help?

Comment: Have you tried to take git out of the picture to see if the problem persists? That is, copying project directory directly between your laptop and desktop.

Comment: yes, thanks, tried your thought this morning.  removing git works.  KingCrunch's response is the fix...my problem was I was adding gitignore after the git init, adding it before init works as intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not version `.project`. Create a file `.gitignore` in your projects root

```
.project
```

But because the file is already versioned you need to remove it from the repository too. `.gitignore` only affects "new" commits, but does not touch the existing ones

```
git rm --cached .project
```